# I don't see the folders of my virtual environment in VS Code even though the Virtual Environment is created. - Newbie

Tags: python, virtual, environment

I created a virtual environment in VS Code (Powershell) microsoft windows (Windows 10). I was able to create the virtual environment but my subfolders containing (bin, include, lib) doesn't show up in the VS Code editor.  When I create it in the cmd prt in VS Code the other folders containing (bin,include,lib) shows up.  I want it to show up in the Powershell mode.  I don't know why it's not showing up.
[No Folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkSwQ.png) [I don't have these folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7c3V.png)

Thanks for your help in advance.

I created a folder, Navigated to it.  Ran pip install virtualenv.  Then I ran virtualenv venv. But no folders where created (atleast didn't show up.)  Then I ran the script .venv\Sripts\activate and the virtual environment what created but the folders didn't show up.  I'm in powershell fyi.